# How does the compiler know which entry in vtable corresponds to a called virtual function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, virtual-functions, vtable

First of all, This question sounds to be repetitive but I explored this over google, but didn't get satisfactory answer as a layman

**Question:**
Let's say we have 3 virtual function in the parent class and derived class as shown in below example

```
class Base1 {
    public :
    virtual void Print1() {
       cout << "Print1 Base1" << endl;
    }
    virtual void Print2() {
       cout << "Print1 Base1" << endl;
    }
    virtual void Print3() {
       cout << "Print1 Base1" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base1 {
public:  
    void Print1() {
       cout << "Print1 Derived1" << endl;
    }
    void Print2() {
       cout << "Print1 Derived2" << endl;
    }
    void Print3() {
       cout << "Print1 Derived3" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base1 *bptr = &d;  
    bptr->Print2(); // -> Here Derived::Print2() shall be called
    return 0;
 }
```

As shown in above example , Derived::Print2() shall be called in main()

Here , Base class and Derived class vTable shall consist of 3 entries for 3 virtual functions

```
 [0] -> Address of Print1()
 [1] -> Address of Print2()
 [2] -> Address of Print3()
```

I wanted to know ,
**At runtime how compiler searches Print2() in Derived vTable ?**

Comment: In most implementations, every object in memory has, as part of its image, a pointer to its type information, including the vtable. Virtual method calls are implemented as an indirection via this pointer through the linked vtable.

Comment: `[1] -> Address of Print2()
 [2] -> Address of Print2()` Why would there be two `Print2()` pointers? Or it's a typo?

Comment: The name is not used at runtime; it becomes "call the third virtual function in the table", which is trivial.

Comment: @KamilCuk , Is was typo

Comment: FYI, the compiler is not accessed during the runtime of a program.  You can compile on one computer and then run the program on another computer that doesn't have the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

There is no searching - the table is not by name but by offset (i.e. it is an array).

In practice, it usually works a lot like this very simplified C-like implementation:

```
// Simplified type; the actual implementation doesn't need to care about the type.
typedef void(*function)(void*);

// Base class
struct Base1 {
    function* vtable;
};

// Derived class
struct Derived
{
    Base1 parent; // The base class subobject    
};

// Virtual members
void Base1_Print1(void*) {
    cout << "Print1 Base1" << endl;
}

void Base1_Print2(void*) {
    cout << "Print2 Base1" << endl;
}

// v-table
function Base1_vtable[2] = { &Base1_Print1, &Base1_Print2 };

// Constructor
void Base1_create(Base1* self)
{
    self->vtable = Base1_vtable;
}

// Overridden members
void Derived_Print2(void*) {
    cout << "Print2 Derived" << endl;
}

// v-table
function Derived_vtable[2] = { &Base_Print1, &Derived_Print2 };

// Constructor
void Derived_create(Derived* self)
{
    Base1_create(&self->parent); // Construct the base subobject
    self->parent.vtable = Derived_vtable; // Adjust the vtable
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Derived_create(&d); // Construct d
    Base1 *bptr = &d.parent; // Implicit conversion made explicit.
    (bptr->vtable[0])(bptr); // Virtual call to Base_Print1
    (bptr->vtable[1])(bptr); // Virtual call to Derived_Print2
 }
```

Comment: In last line "bptr->vtable[1]->(bptr)" -> here how compiler decide to use 1st index of vTable to call Derived_Print2 ?

Comment: The compiler knows from the definition of `Base1` that `Print1` is the first virtual function, and that `Print2` is the second. (The indexes are, of course, an implementation detail just like the existence of the vtable, but it's simple and efficient to implement like this.)

Comment: Thanks , Now I got it by your given code snippet

Comment: The compiler compiled it. For the base class, it just decides any way it likes which virtual function goes where. In order of declaration of virtual functions, in alphabetical order, any way it likes. For a derived class, it uses the same order, then adds any virtual functions that are new in the derived class. The compiler knows because the compiler compiled the code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't search. The correspondence "Print2 is the second entry in the vtable" is established at compile time, when the compiler looks at the definition of the `Base1` class.

Comment: But , then how it jump to second entry , Lets say , we have 100 Print() functions() , and we are calling Print99() ,

Comment: The vtable contains an array with one function pointer for every virtual function. If Print99() is the 110th virtual function in that class, then vtable[109] is a pointer to the implementation of Print99 that should be called.